# How to cast the DataColumnPropertyDescriptor to custom property descriptor?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created the new custom PropertyDescriptor as below,

```
public class CustomPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
    {       


        public CustomPropertyDescriptor (string name, Attribute[] attribute)
            : base(name, attribute)
        {

        }

         ............

         ............
}
```

but when i try to cast this with **DataColumnPropertydescriptor**, it cannot be casted to custom property descriptor. But it is successfully casting to **PropertyDescriptor**(not custom property descriptor)

Is there any solutions available?

Comment: What really are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Ivan, i can get DataColumnPropertyDescriptor instance and i need to cast this object with my custom property descriptor for some customization. I hope you can understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataColumnPropertydescriptor` is not inherited from your `CustomPropertyDescriptor`. It's inherited from `PropertyDescriptor` and does not know anything about your custom class:

```
internal sealed class DataColumnPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
```

Think about this inheritance as if both `Dog` and `Cat` is inherited from `Animal`:

```
public class Dog : Animal

public class Cat: Animal
```

But dog is not cat, and you cannot cast `Dog` to `Cat`:

```
Cat felix = new Cat();
Dog pluto = (Dog)felix; // Of course not working
Animal someAnimal = (Animal)felix; // Cat is animal, so it works
```

That's what you are trying to do now. You can only create new instance of `CustomPropertyDescriptor` and manually copy some data from `DataColumnPropertydescriptor` instance which you have:

```
DataColumnPropertydescriptor columnDescriptor = ...
CustomPropertyDescriptor customDescriptor = 
    new CustomPropertyDescriptor(columnDescriptor.Name, columnDescriptor.Attributes);
```

Comment: Thanks..i can understand but i could not able to find the way to cast the DataColumnPropertyDescriptor. Because DataColumnPropertyDescriptor is sealed class, i cannot get its members and so on..Can you please suggest any solution?

Comment: Cast instance of `DataColumnPropertyDescriptor` to `PropertyDescriptor` and use it's`Name` and `Attributes` properties - both are public. You can also create overloaded constructor for your custom property descriptor which accepts `MemberDescriptor` and pass instance of `DataColumnPropertyDescriptor` there